# What's wrong with this mod_rewrite RewriteRule code?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^$    public/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) public/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

I'm using wamp apache on windows 7. mod_rewrite.so has been enabled in httpd.conf. This code was directly taken from a tutorial found here: http://anantgarg.com/2009/03/13/write-your-own-php-mvc-framework-part-1/

It's purpose is to redirect calls to the ./public folder where the actual logic lies.

I get an internal server error (http 500) when I try to browse index.php in the directory of this .htaccess file. When I remove the two rewriterule statements, it works.

Not sure why, but no error shows up in the logs folder. There is no error log whatsoever.

Any clue on what's going wrong here?

Comment: Did you add the next rule-set to the `public folder` (Root directory in this case, I guess)?

Comment: Hmm? Not sure what you mean exactly!

Comment: There is another rule-set that has to be added, according to the documentation in your link.

Comment: If you get a server error, there should be something in the error log, if the error log is enabled. In your apache config, there must be a line like `ErrorLog .../error.log`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your expression, `(.*)`, matches the target, `/public/something`. The rewrite engine loops until the request URI stops getting changed, and your request URI is turning into `/public/public/public/public/public` etc because there's nothing that stops the rewriting process. Try adding a condition to prevent the loop:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^$   public/     [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
    RewriteRule (.*) public/$1   [L]
</IfModule>
```

So if the request already starts with `/public`, don't apply the rule.

Comment: Would what was originally posted have worked under different circumstances? I had modified the file structure from what he had in the tutorial... Or simplified it. Or maybe those rules would have worked on a previous version of apache?

Comment: @SamLevin I have no idea how the guy in that link got those rules to work without looping.